# Clear or truncate information_schema.copy_history table: Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema, snowflake-pipe

How to clear the table contents from **information_schema.copy_history**

history values so that i can use re-use the same values for copy...strong text

Comment: By "re-use the same values for copy" do you mean copy the same files into a table? If so, you don't need to clear out the copy_history view in the information_schema (and can't unless you drop or replace the table). You can specify FORCE = TRUE in your copy into statement.

Answer (score 0):

Answering for completeness (curating the tags)

As per @Greg in the comments:

By "re-use the same values for copy" do you mean copy the same files into a table? If so, you don't need to clear out the copy_history view in the information_schema (and can't unless you drop or replace the table). You can specify `FORCE = TRUE` in your copy into statement.